# Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password with node mailer

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, nodemailer

I am getting "Error: Invalid login: 535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password" I have correct username and password in there but still get this error. What might be the issue..
[image]

```
  const sendForgotPasswordEmail = (user) => {
    if (!user) { return; }
    const token = user.passwordResetToken;
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'SendGrid',
      auth: {
        user: process.env.SENDGRID_USER,
        pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD
      }
    });
    const mailOptions = {
      to: user.email,
      from: 'mail.mail@com',
      subject: 'Reset your password',
      text: `You are receiving this email because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n
        Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n
        http://${req.headers.host}/reset/${token}\n\n
        If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n`
    };
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
      .then(() => {
        req.flash('info', { msg: `An e-mail has been sent to ${user.email} with further instructions.` });
      });
  };

  createRandomToken
    .then(setRandomToken)
    .then(sendForgotPasswordEmail)
    .then(() => res.redirect('/forgot'))
    .catch(next);
```

Answer (score 3):

Although you didn't specify, from your cross-posting on Github and the screenshot of the error, your issue is more specifically that you are getting a username/password error when using [*Hackathon Starter*](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter) (with *SendGrid* setup) ; and the project under its hood uses nodemailer.

I have tested Hackathon Starter with SendGrid and a valid username/password, and it worked as intended, so it is not an issue with Hackathon Starter or Nodemailer.  So in your specific case, according to the error that you posted SendGrid is responding that the username and password they received doesn't correspond to a valid username password in their system.  I would suggest:

1. Login to SendGrid on their website and re-verify the username and password.  Note that the API keys that SendGrid provides are NOT the username and password; they are intended for a different purpose than SMTP mail authentication with SendGrid.  You need to use the Username/Password under Account Details in SendGrid.
2. Check your environment variables to verify that they are set properly with your SendGrid "username" and "password".  Note that most likely you will not need to add any single or double quotes around your username and password (at least that is the way it is working for me).  You can temporarily add debug code like the following in your code for checking that your environment variables are set properly.

   `console.log "SENDGRID_USER env variable is set as:", process.env.SENDGRID_USER`
   `console.log "SENDGRID_PASSWORD env variable is set as:", process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD`

Make sure to remove this debug code after verification, since having the password going into the console log as clear text can become a security issue.

By the way, in your `mailOptions` you may want to change the `from:` field to a valid email address that corresponds to one of your project's email addresses/aliases.

Comment: Have used the same password and username that ships with hackerthon starter but still get the same error. Am running it locally on node 8.0.

Comment: Why are you using the username password of someone else?  Why should a username password that is publicly posted on the internet be valid for anyone to use and abuse?  You need to create an account with the service provider, agree to their terms of service, and use your own username and password instead of dummy username password that is posted with the project as a placeholder. See the Readme for Hackathon Starter - Sendgrid : "Go to https://sendgrid.com/user/signup , Sign up and confirm your account via the activation email , Then enter your SendGrid Username and Password into .env file"

Answer (score 0):

535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password

SOLUTION:
Check the menu Email API --> Integration Guide, select SMTP and NOT Api, and NOT api, then, following the steps, and as username you will have "apikey" and password will be the long api key.

[image]
[image]